# Multiple model in one form with one to many relation with Select2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a relation on my database like this :

[image: Relation]

My goal is, when I am inserting a record into bukti_penerimaan table, I also save a lot of record into `bukti_penerimaan_invoice` table and also a lot of record in `bukti_penerimaan_debit_note` table.

**Model**

```
<?php
    class BuktiPenerimaan extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{

        public function getBuktiPenerimaanDebitNotes(){
            return $this->hasMany(BuktiPenerimaanDebitNote::className(), ['bukti_penerimaan_id' => 'id']);
        }

        public function getBuktiPenerimaanInvoices(){
            return $this->hasMany(BuktiPenerimaanInvoice::className(), ['bukti_penerimaan_id' => 'id']);
        }
    }
?>
```

So this is the actionCreate, which is successfully work.

**Controller**

```
public function actionCreate(){
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $model = new BuktiPenerimaan(); // one record
    $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice = new BuktiPenerimaanInvoice(); // to many record
    $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote = new BuktiPenerimaanDebitNote(); // to many record

    if ($request->isAjax) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        if ($request->isGet) { // which is fine
            return [
                'title' => "Create new BuktiPenerimaan",
                'content' => $this->renderAjax('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice' => $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice,
                    'modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote' => $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote
                ]),
                'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])

            ];
        } else if ($model->load($request->post())&& $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote->load($request->post())&& $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice->load($request->post())
                    && Model::validateMultiple([$model, $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote, $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice])) {

            //doing transaction here. ;

        } else{
            return [
                'title' => "Create new BuktiPenerimaan",
                'content' => $this->renderAjax('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice' => $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice,
                    'modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote' => $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote
                ]),
                'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])

            ];
        }
    }
}
```

**view : create.php**

```
    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice' => $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice,
        'modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote' => $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote
]) ?>
```

**view _form.php**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'rekening')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'maxlength' => true]) ?>

    /*Find standard invoices*/
    <?php $dataInvoice = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\finance\Invoice::find()->all(), 'id', 'nomor_surat'); ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice, 'invoice_id')->widget(Select2::className(), [
        'data' => $dataInvoice,
        'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Select Invoice / Invoices ...']
        ]); ?>

    /*Find standard debit_notes*/
    <?php $dataDebitNote = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\finance\DebitNote::find()->all(), 'id', 'nomor_surat'); ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote, 'debit_note_id')->widget(Select2::className(), [
        'data' => $dataDebitNote,
        'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Select Debit Note / Debit Notes ...']
    ]); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Everything is fine.

But when in actionUpdate, I got an error.

**Controller**

```
<?php   
public function actionUpdate($id){
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    try {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
    } catch (NotFoundHttpException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice = $model->buktiPenerimaanInvoices;
    $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote = $model->buktiPenerimaanDebitNotes;

    if ($request->isAjax) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        if ($request->isGet) {
            return [
                'title' => "Update BuktiPenerimaan #" . $id,
                'content' => $this->renderAjax('update', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote' => $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote,
                    'modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice' => $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice,
                ]),
                'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])
            ];
        } else if ($model->load($request->post())
            && $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote->load($request->post())
            && $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice->load($request->post())
            && Model::validateMultiple([$model, $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote, $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice])) {
            return [
                'forceReload' => '#crud-datatable-pjax',
                'title' => "BuktiPenerimaan #" . $id,
                'content' => $this->renderAjax('view', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]),
                'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::a('Edit', ['update', 'id' => $id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'modal-remote'])
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                'title' => "Update BuktiPenerimaan #" . $id,
                'content' => $this->renderAjax('update', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote' => $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote,
                    'modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice' => $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice,
                ]),
                'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])
            ];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The error is

```
"name":"PHP Fatal Error","message":"Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array","code":1,"type":"yii\\base\\ErrorException"
```

The problem is in :

```
    <?php $dataInvoice = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\finance\Invoice::find()->all(), 'id', 'nomor_surat'); ?>
<?= $form->field($modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice, 'invoice_id')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'data' => $dataInvoice,
    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Select Invoice / Invoices ...']
]); ?>

<?php $dataDebitNote = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\finance\DebitNote::find()->all(), 'id', 'nomor_surat'); ?>
<?= $form->field($modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote, 'debit_note_id')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'data' => $dataDebitNote,
    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Select Debit Note / Debit Notes ...']
]); ?>
```

How can to Yii2 recognized it as a form one to many relation.

**Update**

This is the actionFindModel looks like :

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = BuktiPenerimaan::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Please an advise.

Comment: can you add `findModel()` function and when you say the problem is in these form fields did you confirmed that by removing them from the form? and are you loading the edit form via `ajax`

Answer (score 1):

In "BuktiPenerimaan" model you have defined two one-to-many relations :  "getBuktiPenerimaanDebitNotes" and "getBuktiPenerimaanInvoices".

```
public function getBuktiPenerimaanDebitNotes(){
            return $this->hasMany(BuktiPenerimaanDebitNote::className(), ['bukti_penerimaan_id' => 'id']);
        }

        public function getBuktiPenerimaanInvoices(){
            return $this->hasMany(BuktiPenerimaanInvoice::className(), ['bukti_penerimaan_id' => 'id']);
        }
```

In actionCreate, you have created the instance of BuktiPenerimaanInvoice and BuktiPenerimaanDebitNote . Then you load the post data and perform validation. Everything good here.

```
$modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice = new BuktiPenerimaanInvoice(); // to many record
    $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote = new BuktiPenerimaanDebitNote(); // to many record
```

But, in actionUpdate, you have used the below code and it returns you one to many relations which are collections of models (an array of models) :

```
$modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice = $model->buktiPenerimaanInvoices;
    $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote = $model->buktiPenerimaanDebitNotes;
```

You are using the below code to perform validation :

```
$modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote->load($request->post())
            && $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice->load($request->post())
            && Model::validateMultiple([$model, $modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote, $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice])) {
```

"validateMultiple" calls "validate" method of each of the specified models . Two of those models ($modelsBuktiPenerimaanDebitNote, $modelsBuktiPenerimaanInvoice) are collections and not objects. So, calling "validate" on collection raising the error

```
"name":"PHP Fatal Error","message":"Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array","code":1,"type":"yii\\base\\ErrorException"
```

Comment: that is what OP has already notified and not what he required you havent proposed a solution to him

Comment: Question was this: "How can to Yii2 recognized it as a form one to many relation " . I  mentioned why the error is happening and what causing the error. OP never asked for a solution.